# Tensorflow Recommenders fit Expected string, but got Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(None,), dtype=string) of type 'Tensor'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to follow the tutorial on the Tensorflow quickstart page [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/recommenders/examples/quickstart). However, instead of using the movie-lens data used I am trying to use the Movie Dataset found at [Kaggle Here](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rounakbanik/the-movies-dataset?select=ratings_small.csv). When I try to fit the model I get the following error

```
Epoch 1/3
WARNING:tensorflow:Layers in a Sequential model should only have a single input tensor. Received: inputs={'movieId': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None,) dtype=int64>, 'userId': <tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:1' shape=(None,) dtype=string>}. Consider rewriting this model with the Functional API.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-b20246ea89fa> in <module>
      4 
      5 # Train for 3 epochs.
----> 6 model.fit(ratings_tf.batch(4096), epochs=3)
      7 

3 frames
<ipython-input-31-50917ec57dbf> in compute_loss(self, features, training)
     23 
     24     user_embeddings = self.user_model(features["userId"])
---> 25     movie_embeddings = self.movie_model(features) #movie_embeddings = self.movie_model(features["title"])
     26 
     27     return self.task(user_embeddings, movie_embeddings)

TypeError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1160, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1146, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1135, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow_recommenders/models/base.py", line 68, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(inputs, training=True)
    File "<ipython-input-31-50917ec57dbf>", line 25, in compute_loss
        movie_embeddings = self.movie_model(features) #movie_embeddings = self.movie_model(features["title"])
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

    TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "string_lookup_1" "                 f"(type StringLookup).
    
    Expected string, but got Tensor("IteratorGetNext:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int64) of type 'Tensor'.
    
    Call arguments received by layer "string_lookup_1" "                 f"(type StringLookup):
      • inputs={'movieId': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=int64)', 'userId': 'tf.Tensor(shape=(None,), dtype=string)'}
```

The data I am using includes the `ratings_small.csv`, `links_small.csv` and `movie_metadata.csv'. The output of the datasets can be found below

[image]

[image]

The code I have so far is below.

```
movies_df = movies_df.dropna()
movies_df['release_date'] = pd.to_datetime(movies_df['release_date'])
movies_df['year'] = movies_df['release_date'].dt.year

# Select the basic features.
ratings_tf = ratings[['movieId', 'userId']] #['movie_title'] #= 
ratings_tf['userId'] = ratings_tf['userId'].astype(str)
movies_tf = movies_df.dropna().drop('year', axis=1)['title']

years = []
for movie in movies_tf :
  yr = movies_df[movies_df['title']==movie]['year'].values[0]
  id = movies_df[movies_df['title']==movie]['id'].values[0]
  years.append(yr)

for i in range(len(movies_tf)) :
  movies_tf.reset_index()[i] = (movies_tf.reset_index(drop=True)[i] + ' (' + str(years[i]) + ')')

indexes = movies_tf.index
movies_tf = [movies_tf.reset_index(drop=True)[i] + ' (' + str(years[i]) + ')' for i in range(len(movies_tf))]
movies_tf = pd.DataFrame(data=movies_tf, columns=['title']).set_index(indexes)
movies_tf = movies_tf[['title']]

movies_tf = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(movies_tf))
ratings_tf = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(ratings_tf))

movies_tf = movies_tf.map(lambda x: x["title"])

ratings_tf = ratings_tf.map(lambda x: {
"movieId": x["movieId"],
"userId": x["userId"]
 })

user_ids_vocabulary = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(mask_token=None)
user_ids_vocabulary.adapt(ratings_tf.map(lambda x: x["userId"]))
movie_titles_vocabulary = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(mask_token=None)
movie_titles_vocabulary.adapt(movies_tf)

class MovieLensModel(tfrs.Model):
  # We derive from a custom base class to help reduce boilerplate. Under the hood,
  # these are still plain Keras Models.

  def __init__(
      self,
      user_model: tf.keras.Model,
      movie_model: tf.keras.Model,
      task: tfrs.tasks.Retrieval):
    super().__init__()

    # Set up user and movie representations.
    self.user_model = user_model
    self.movie_model = movie_model

    # Set up a retrieval task.
    self.task = task

  def compute_loss(self, features: Dict[Text, tf.Tensor], training=False) -> tf.Tensor:
    # Define how the loss is computed.

    user_embeddings = self.user_model(features["userId"])
    movie_embeddings = self.movie_model(features) #movie_embeddings = self.movie_model(features["title"])

    return self.task(user_embeddings, movie_embeddings)

 Define user model
user_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    user_ids_vocabulary,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(user_ids_vocabulary.vocabulary_size(), 64)
])

# Define movie model
movie_model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    movie_titles_vocabulary,
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(movie_titles_vocabulary.vocabulary_size(), 64)
])

# Define the objectives.
task = tfrs.tasks.Retrieval(metrics=tfrs.metrics.FactorizedTopK(
    movies_tf.map(movie_model)
  )
)

# Create a retrieval model.
model = MovieLensModel(user_model, movie_model, task)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adagrad(0.5))

# Train for 3 epochs.
model.fit(ratings_tf.batch(4096), epochs=3)
```

Any and all help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: @furas. Sorry about that. Due to maintenance, I could not edit my post yesterday. Anyways I added the full error now